# IP Filtering IIS7

Tags: iis-7

Is it possible to stop IIS7 from logging certain IP addresses?

We have a large amount of dynamic links in our Google Adwords account (over 250,000) and they are visited by the Google Bot nearly every day leading to huge amounts of entries in the web log, so I would like to stop visits from the bot being logged.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible as far as I know.  However, it's trivial to write a log cleaner, or to use off-the-shelf analytics software to exclude IPs.